# Feature query for grid in IE

Tags: css

I'm using a feature query, my goal is to display grid on all browsers except IE. IE doesn't support feature queries, so all code in the feature query will be ignored.

It's working for me in IE, but on Chrome/all other browsers the code outside of the feature query is applying styles, but the feature query is still working like it's displaying `grid`, but also taking the `margin`/`padding` from the code outside of the feature query. Is there a way around this?

feature query

```
 @supports(grid-auto-rows:auto){
    .Gallery{
      display:-ms-grid;
      display:grid;
      grid-gap: 5px;
      grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(170px, 1fr));
      grid-auto-rows:95px;
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
    }  

    .horiz{
      -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
      grid-column: span 2;
    }
    .vert{
      -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
      grid-row: span 2;
    }
    .big{
      -ms-grid-column-span:2;
      grid-column:span 2;
      -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
      grid-row: span 2;
    }

    .imgContainer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -o-object-fit: cover;
         object-fit: cover;
    }

  }
```

styles outside of the feature query that's being applied

```
.Gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -1em 0 1em -0.5em;
}

.img {
  padding: 1em 0 0 0.5em;
  flex: 1 0;
  min-width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Put your feature-query CSS after your non-feature-query CSS.

Comment: Thats how it is in my text editor, I don't know why i wrote it backwards here, but thats how i have it.

Comment: You could just add `margin: 0;` to the feature-query.

Comment: Even though chrome supports grid-auto-rows:auto  it is still taking on the styles outside of the feature query, not only the margin, but I checked dev tools and it says display:flex and it's taking on the padding too...